# Playframework with CSRF : "CSRF token not found in session"?

Tags: playframework, csrf, playframework-2.3

I'm making a simple authentication system using Playframework with their built-in CSRF filter and Security.Authenticator system, but I'm facing a problem :

When the user fill his login/password and submit enter, I have the following error :

> CSRF token not found in session

I checked my form and the CSRF token is really present and correctly placed (inside the  tag)

Here is my `routes` :

```
GET     /login                      controllers.Authentication.login
POST    /login                      controllers.Authentication.authenticate
```

And my `Authentication.java` class :

```
@play.filters.csrf.AddCSRFToken
public static Result login() {
    if (Session.getAccount() != null) {
        return redirect(controllers.routes.Instances.list());
    }

    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
    if (ctx().session().containsKey("email")) {
        loginForm.setEmail(ctx().session().get("email"));
    }

    if (request().queryString().containsKey("disconnected")) {
        flash("warning", Messages.get("secure.logout")); // TODO : Warning flash message
    }

    Form<LoginForm> form = Form.form(LoginForm.class).fill(loginForm);
    return ok(views.html.login.render(form));
}

@play.filters.csrf.AddCSRFToken
@play.filters.csrf.RequireCSRFCheck
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<LoginForm> form = Form.form(LoginForm.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (form.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(views.html.login.render(form));
    }

    LoginForm login = form.get();
    Account account = Account.findByEmail(login.getEmail());

    if (account == null || !account.checkPassword(login.getPassword())) {
        form.reject("email", "secure.invalid.login");
        return badRequest(views.html.login.render(form));
    }

    String next = null;
    if (ctx().session().containsKey("next")) {
        next = ctx().session().get("next");
        if ("".equals(next)) {
            next = null;
        }
    }

    session().clear();
    session("email", login.getEmail());

    if (next != null) {
        return redirect(next);
    } else {
        return redirect(controllers.routes.Instances.list());
    }
}
```

The properties I setted in the application.conf :

```
csrf.token.name="csrf"
csrf.sign.tokens=true
```

Here's my form (to show that the token is correctly positionned) :

```
<form action="@controllers.routes.Authentication.authenticate" method="post" class="form-vertical" role="form">
    <fieldset>
        @defining(form("email")) { element =>
        <div class="form-group fade-in two@if(element.hasErrors){ has-error}">
            <label class="control-label" for="login-form-@element.name">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="@element.name" id="login-form-@element.name" class="form-control" value="@element.value" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
            @element.errors.map { error => <span class="help-block">@play.i18n.Messages.get(error.message)</span>}
        </div>}
        @defining(form("password")) { element =>
        <div class="form-group fade-in three@if(element.hasErrors){ has-error}">
            <label class="control-label" for="login-form-@element.name">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="@element.name" id="login-form-@element.name" class="form-control" value="@element.value" placeholder="Enter your password" required />
            @element.errors.map { error => <span class="help-block">@play.i18n.Messages.get(error.message)</span>}
        </div>}
        <div class="form-group actions fade-in four">
            <div class="text-right">
                <input type="submit" name="save" value="Sign me in" class="btn btn-primary" />
                @helper.CSRF.formField
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Update 1**: I removed all the `@addCSRFToken` and `@requireCSRFToken` and defined a global CSRF token instead, per @rhj recommandation. Now I got this error instead :

> Invalid token found in form body

But as you can see in the HTML Form, the token is placed inside the form and should be identified!

**Update 2**: What bothers me the most, is that this problem only occurs in the Login page, and not elsewhere! Is there some session to enable first? I guess not but maybe ?!

**Update 3**: More odd, I just found out that if I change the value of `csrf.token.name` and reload the page, it works. Then if I log out, open a new page and try to logs again, it fails with the message `Invalid token found in form body`. If I again change the value of `csrf.token.name` and do it again, it will works again.

**Update 4**: I narrowed down the problem. I also use the play.mvc.Security.Authenticator and it seems that the token verification fails ONLY when I display the page after a `redirect()`. If I go straight to the login page, I won't have the error message displayed.

**Final update!** : I finally found the problem, it was in another class that I wasn't suspecting, that was called and cleared the session, making the token useless!

Comment: The error message indicates that Play can't find the token in your cookie. Play hasn't yet reached the stage where it looks for the token in your form. Do you see the token present in your cookie? Are you using any of the ``csrf.xxx`` configuration properties to configure the CSRF filter? If so, what happens if you revert to the default configuration?

Comment: Yes indeed, seems to work. I updated the information of the question to reflect the properties I used in the .conf file

Comment: Finally no, I sometimes get the same error, even with all the configuration of the CSRF filter removed :/

Comment: sorry for asking so bluntly, but I am facing a similar issue, and I was wondering if you have a github repo with this complete project. I am 'attempting' to learn Play! but progress is slow.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the only repository I have regarding Play is this one [play2.2 subproject](https://github.com/cnicodeme/play2.2-subproject). Not sure it will help you :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally the problem was located in an other part of my code that was cleaning the session in the `login()` method, removing the csrf token with it ...

Answer (score 3):

Add the below line in **Global.java**

```
@Override
public <T extends EssentialFilter> Class<T>[] filters() {
    return new Class[]{CSRFFilter.class};
}
```

For this you have to import

```
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I tried to set the CSRF global, but unfortunately no, it doesn't change at all. I still have the following error : `No CSRF token found in headers`

Comment: Or else, I sometime also got this message : `Invalid token found in form body`. Don't understand why this is occuring!

Comment: I finally found the problem, that was located in an other part of the code, but since you are the only answer and the bounty will be destroyed, I give it to you ;)