# Play Login not catching CSRF token

Tags: playframework, csrf, csrf-protection, playframework-2.6

I'm doing some simple login validation on my Play! 2.6 framework web app, and it seems to not pick up the CSRF token that I include on the `view.loginForm`:

```
@import helper.CSRF

@(loginform: Form[UserLoginData])(implicit messages: MessagesProvider, request: RequestHeader)

@main() {
        <div class="row">
            <form method="post" class="col-md-6" id="loginform" autocomplete="on">
               @CSRF.formField
            <input type="text id="userName">
             <!-- other inputs and submit button-->
             </form>
        </div>
}
```

and then my conf.routes handles the POST'ing by:

`POST    /login                      controllers.LoginRegController.attemptLogin`

And here's the method in the `LoginRegController` :

```
def attemptLogin() = Action {
        implicit request: Request[AnyContent] => {
          loginform.bindFromRequest().fold(
            formWithErrors => BadRequest(views.html.login(formWithErrors)),
            successfulForm => {
              // check DB for valid inputs
                val userName = //retrieved from form
                Ok(views.html.afterLogin.dashboardviews.dashboard())
                  .withSession(request.session + ("authenticated" -> "true") + ("username" -> userName))
                  .withHeaders(SecurityHeadersFilter
                    .CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_HEADER -> " .fonts.googleapis.com ")
            }
          )
        }
      }
```

As soon as the user hits submit, it gets taken to the framework's default Authorized page, and I see on my console that it has failed the CSRF check:

> [warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because no token found in
>   headers

I'm thinking that there's a similar problem as mentioned in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136744/playframework-with-csrf-csrf-token-not-found-in-session) in that the session is being refreshed, but I would think it would have the token in the request itself, pass the test, and then load up a new session. Any ideas how to fix, or how to grab the token and "insert" it where necessary here in the Controller method?

Comment: This looks fine. The question you linked to is using play 2.3 -- 2.6 adds play filter by default. I think your intuition regarding "it would have the token in the request itself, pass the test, and then load up a new session" is correct as filters (like CSRF) wrap the action. When you inspect the form in the browser -- do you see a CSRF token?

Comment: @tgk I definitely do, it's a nice hidden input with `name="csrfToken"`. I don't know what happened, I've been fiddling with little things all day and another huge issue, but I restarted IntelliJ and now it has no problems. It's just been one of those days.

Comment: Glad its working at least =P